# How to scrape text from an html page using C#?

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

I have a web page that when navigated to only returns a simple text value, like the number 100. I need to grab that value from the page, so I can use it in my application. The application is a simple Windows Forms app, with a web browser control on it.

I have tried numerous things, but it's not grabbing the text, as if it doesn't exist. Yet if I right click and view source, it's there.

This can't be that difficult...It's just some text.

Just to clarify the document contains NO html, only a number. When using WebClient or WebRequest, it doesn't return the value.

```
    private void RegisterWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("MYURL");
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

    }

    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check and see if we have navigated to the final page.
        string registeredUrl = "MYURL";
        string currentPage = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
        string response = string.Empty;

        if (webBrowser1.Url.ToString() == registeredUrl)
        {
            // Now parse the authkey from the url
            response = GetWebRequest(currentPage);
            MessageBox.Show(response);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Send a Web Request and get a Web Response back. 
    /// This respons can be a valid URL, simple text response, or 
    /// HTML response.        
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetWebRequest(string url)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        var content = client.DownloadString(url);

        return content;
    }
```

Comment: what code are you using when using WebClient or WebRequest?

Comment: Use Fiddler to compare the requests.

Comment: You need to provide more details (sample code) on what you have tried and what didn't work.

Comment: Let's see your code, WebRequest should work but you might need to enable cookies, change your user agent, etc... to make it work!

Comment: Just added the code...The page itself just returns a number in plain text format.

Comment: Best guess would be that you have to fill in the user-agent. As @Slaks pointed out compare the requests with Fiddler to find out what is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the document contains only number without any HTML, this should work:

```
public string GetWebRequest()
{
    return webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: If this worked for you, Carl, it means your web page is returning more than just the number in text: this line is accessing the content of the <body> tag of the page.  That means you're returning a whole HTML page whose content inside its <body> tag is the number you're looking for.

Comment: @atanamir Carl stated that the document contains only number. I tried simulating his code and browse a text file which contains only a number and this code returns the content of the text file. If you are browsing an HTML page, then this code will return all html (edit: inner text, not html) inside the body.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something as straightforward as:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var content = client.DownloadString("<YOUR URL>");
var number = Int32.Parse(content);
```

[MSDN documentation for DownloadString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: +1: Good option if you don't need cookies; simpler than mine. [.NET 4 documentation link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) Note that you should wrap WebClient in a using block, as it is IDisposable.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a blog post on [Web scraping in .NET](http://www.truewill.net/myblog/index.php/2007/12/30/web_scraping_in_net) several years ago. You could try the techniques there. Hopefully they're not obsolete.

For example:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

request.UserAgent = _UserAgent;
request.CookieContainer = cookies;  // optional

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
  using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
  {
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
      html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
  }
}
```

Remember that your browser is sending a [User-Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) header, may be sending cookies, may be going through a configured proxy server, etc. Particularly for secured or intranet sites, a simple WebClient call may be insufficient. You may need to do some checking with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) as @SLaks suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the page HTML/TXT content to a string then use a string function to extract the number.